# How to calcucalate the distance agent moved

Tags: anylogic

guys

Have the population of trucks in model, moving from city to city. How to calculate the distance, every truck has moved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways... one very accurate that requires your cities to be agents, and the other less accurate that doesn't require that.

**Option 1:** (accurate, requires agents)

1. Your truck is moving from city1 to city2, both are agents and you want to know the distance between city1 and the truck (which is equal to the distance moved)
2. calculate: `city1.distanceByRoute(truck)` whenever you need to know the distance moved.

**Option 2** (less accurate, doesn't requires agents)

1. Create a variable called `initialTime=time();` (it takes the value time() when the truck starts the journey.
2. Calculate `(time()-iniTime)*truck.getSpeed()` whenever you want to know the distance moved.